# Multiple jQuery UI sliders updating the wrong values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, meta-boxes

I'm using the Wordpress Meta Box plug-in (https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box) to place six jQuery UI sliders on a post page.

Problem is that there must be an error in the jQuery that handles the sliders I can't find: everytime I put multiple sliders, it updates the value of the last slider in the page instead of the correct one. Works fine only with 1 slider in the page, or If I repeat the code six times (once for each class), which obviously I don't wanna do.

Example:

I move **pm_slider_c1** > Updates **pm_rating_c6-label** span

Here's the JS code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ )
{
    var
        id = null
        , el = null
        , input = null
        , label = null
        , format = null
        , value = null
        , update = null
        ;
    $( '.rwmb-slider' ).each( function( i, val )
    {
        id = $( val ).attr( 'id' );
        el = $( '#' + id );
        input = $( '[name=' + id + ']' );
        label = $( '[for=' + id + ']' );
        format = $( el ).attr( 'rel' );

        $( label ).append( ': <span id="' + id + '-label"></span>' );
        update = $( '#' + id + '-label' );

        if (
            !$( input ).val()
                || 'undefined' === $( input ).val()
                || null === typeof $( input ).val()
            )
        {
            $( input ).val( $( el ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
            $( update ).text( "0" );
        }
        else
        {
            value = $( input ).val();
            $( update ).text( value );
        }
        if ( 0 < format.length )
            $( update ).append( ' ' + format );

        el.slider(
            {
                value: value,
                slide: function( event, ui )
                {
                    $( input ).val( ui.value );
                    $( update ).text( ui.value + ' ' + format );
                }
            } );
    } );
} );
```

HTML OF A SINGLE SLIDER:

```
<div class="rwmb-field rwmb-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="rwmb-label">
        <label for="pm_rating_c1">Rating: 
            <span id="pm_rating_c1-label">0</span><!-- GENERATED FROM JS -->
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="rwmb-input">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="rwmb-slider" id="pm_rating_c1"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="pm_rating_c1" value="0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's four days I'm having a headache on this (I'm no jQuery expert), so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks guys

Comment: I guess the error must be somewhere here at the end, or in the used variables:  

`$( update ).text( ui.value + ' ' + format );`  

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question trying to solve a similar issue.

For anyone's reference: The problem is that the input and update values are being reset each time the slider is created (for every iteration of the each() loop).

Thus when any ui slider object detects the slide event it calls the following logic using the last values you set for 'input' and 'update'

```
$( input ).val( ui.value );
$( update ).text( ui.value + ' ' + format );
```

The solution is to use a jquery this object **$(this)** as the root of a selector.

E.G.

```
el.slider(
            {
                value: value,
                slide: function( event, ui )
                {
                    $(this).find("input").val( ui.value );
                    $(this).closest("label").text( ui.value + ' ' + format );
                }
            } );
```

It is possible that there is a more efficient way of writing this, but it addresses the root of your problem.